# Python Kivy referencing between classes

Tags: python, kivy

Here's the relevant .py code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

import random

class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LevelOneBedroomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LevelOneBedroomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def next_text(self):
        if self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text == '*YAWN*':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source = 'placeholder_background2.png'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'Hello'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text == 'Hello':
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'   

class LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_image(self):
        #This part is not working
        self.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice_image.source = LevelOneBedroomScreen.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source


class screensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screensApp().run()
```

Near the bottom I commented the part of the code that does not work.  I have two, nearly identical screens where one LevelOneBedroomScreen has text and LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen has buttons.  I need both background images to be the same, and since the first screen updates images occasionally I wrote something in the .kv file to hopefully pull the image from the first screen but it results in an error.  Here is the relevant code from the .kv:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<RootScreen>:
    transition: FadeTransition() 
    LevelOneBedroomScreen:
    LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen:

<LevelOneBedroomScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom'
    id: level_one_bedroom
    Image:
        id: level_one_bedroom_image
        source: 'placeholder_background.png'
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Image of Bedroom'
        Button:
            text: 'Dialogue'
            background_color: 0,0,0,0       
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .2
        Label:
            text: 'left arrow'
        Button:
            text: 'choose'  
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'           
        Label:
            text: 'right arrow'         
<LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom choice'
    id: level_one_bedroom_choice
    Image:
        id: level_one_bedroom_choice_image
        source: get_image()
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Image of Bedroom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: 'choice 1'
                Button:
                    text: 'choice 2'
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: 'choice 3'
                Button:
                    text: 'choice 4'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .2
            Label:
                text: 'left arrow'
            Button:
                text: 'home'    
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'levels'         
            Label:
                text: 'right arrow'
```

I inserted a comment showing which part of the code results in error. Thank you in advance, greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Do you want LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen when LevelOneBedroomScreen also changes background?

Comment: what is `level_one_bedroom_text`?, provide a [mcve]

Comment: When LevelOneBedroomScreen changes background, I want LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen to have the same background

Comment: what is level_one_bedroom_text?

Comment: level_one_bedroom_text is the id for the layout containing text that I've excluded from the .kv, it wasn't relevant I apologize it was confusing.

Comment: please put all the necessary code so that your code is reproducible, you can think now that it is irrelevant but if you realize its logic depends on it so it is relevant.

Comment: I don't have the original code with me, but I recreated what I could from this post and edited the OP.  The code now is able to run, and I have left a comment in the .py and .kv to show the problem area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Kivy Screen Manager](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html), replace *LevelOneBedroomScreen.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source* with *self.manager.ids.level_one_bedroom.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source*

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Home(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LevelOneBedroomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LevelOneBedroomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def next_text(self):
        if self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text == '*YAWN*':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source = 'placeholder_background2.png'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'Hello'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text == 'Hello':
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'


class LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice_image.source = self.manager.ids.level_one_bedroom.ids.level_one_bedroom_image.source


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Home()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Home>:
    LevelOneBedroomScreen:
        id: level_one_bedroom
    LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen:
        id: level_one_bedroom_choice

<LevelOneBedroomScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            id: level_one_bedroom_image
            source: 'bedroom.jpeg'  # 'placeholder_background.png'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: 'Bedroom Choice'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'

<LevelOneBedroomChoiceScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom choice'
    Image:
        id: level_one_bedroom_choice_image
        #below is the code that fails
        # source:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Bedroom Choice Screen]

Comment: Thank you very much @ikolim, this solves my issue.  I've tried a few things but this is definitely the cleanest solution.